# Unable to identify the touches in customview embedded in UIScrollView due to resetting the contentoffset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a UIScrollView which holds a custom drawing view. The drawing view is used to draw a large content (10000x10000 pixels). Since I cannot embed huge view inside scrollview [due memory limitations], I have created a custom view which is almost twice the size of the scrollView. I have used the StreetScroller [apple sample] logic to implement the same. This works fine but there is a problem with identifying touches. You can download the updated sample from here https://github.com/praveencastelino/SampleApps/tree/master/StreetScroller

Since the contentOffset of scrollview is reset to center whenever it moves 'X amount of pixels' from its center. Hence, the scrollView content offset is different from what we actually need. This what we do in scrollView.

```
- (void)recenterIfNecessary
{
  CGPoint currentOffset = [self contentOffset];
  CGFloat contentHeight = [self contentSize].height;

  CGFloat contentWidth = [self contentSize].width;

  CGPoint centerOffset,distanceFromCenter;
  centerOffset.y = (contentHeight - [self bounds].size.height) / 2.0;
  distanceFromCenter.y  = fabs(currentOffset.y - centerOffset.y);

  centerOffset.x = (contentWidth - [self bounds].size.width) / 2.0;
  distanceFromCenter.x  = fabs(currentOffset.x - centerOffset.x);

  if (distanceFromCenter.y > (contentHeight / 6.0))
  {
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffset.x, centerOffset.y);
    [_labelContainerView didResetByVerticalDistancePoint:CGPointMake(currentOffset.x, centerOffset.y - currentOffset.y) visibleFrame:[self bounds]];
  }


  if (distanceFromCenter.x > (contentWidth / 6.0))
  {
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(centerOffset.x, currentOffset.y);
    [_labelContainerView didResetByHorizontalDistancePoint: CGPointMake(centerOffset.x - currentOffset.x, currentOffset.y) visibleFrame:[self bounds]];
  }

}
```

Whenever scrollview resets the center, the custom view notified and it tracks the virtual content offset.

```
-(void)didResetByVerticalDistancePoint:(CGPoint)distance visibleFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
  _contentOffsetY += distance.y;
  NSLog(@"_contentOffsetY %f",_contentOffsetY);
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }
```

However, I wanted to calculate the virtual content offset whenever scroll view scrolls [At present the content offset is calculated only when we reset content offset of scrollview to center]. This would eventually help me in handling touches.

Also, I need a way to restrict the bounds of the scrollview from scrolling infinitely. I want to display only the content and avoid the scrolling if user tries to scroll it further.